# Cannot GET /listUsers Nodejs Error

Tags: node.js

I'm using the tutorial found here: http://www.runoob.com/nodejs/nodejs-restful-api.html and added the following code.

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var fs=require('fs');
app.get('listUsers',function(req,res){
   fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json",'utf-8',function(err,data){
      console.log(data);
       res.end(data);
   });

});
var server=app.listen(8081,function(){
    var host=server.address().address;
    var port=server.address().port;
   // console.log("应用实例，访问地址为 http://%s:%s",host,port);
})
```

After debug the server with IntelliJ IDEA test.js I'm getting an error stating Cannot GET / when I access localhost:8081/listUsers and I just wondered if anyone knew much about this error as Express and Node are new to me?

this is my json file:users.json

```
 {
   "user1" : {
      "name" : "mahesh",
      "password" : "password1",
      "profession" : "teacher",
      "id": 1
   },
   "user2" : {
      "name" : "suresh",
      "password" : "password2",
      "profession" : "librarian",
      "id": 2
   },
   "user3" : {
      "name" : "ramesh",
      "password" : "password3",
      "profession" : "clerk",
      "id": 3
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the back slash in app.get('/listUsers').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed backward slash before listUsers route. this will certainly work

```
app.get('/listUsers',function(req,res){
   fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json",'utf-8',function(err,data){
      console.log(data);
       res.end(data);
   });

});
```